# How to allow user to attach text with marker at runtime Leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i know the code like how to attach text with marker so when user click on marker then that text will shown in tooltips.

here is code which i know

```
map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer(CM_URL, { attribution: CM_ATTR, styleId: 997 }).addTo(map);

            L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();



            L.polygon([
                [51.509, -0.08],
                [51.503, -0.06],
                [51.51, -0.047]
            ]).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/p6ssbvqj/6/

my concern is when i allow user to work with drawing control then how could i allow user to put text with marker on map as a result when user will later click on marker or circle then those entered text will be shown in tool tips.

please help me to get the code which allow user to attach text with marker and misc shape at runtime. i know how to work with drawing control. here is a sample demo http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/yyetbb1j/

looking for help. thanks

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111464/leaflet-draw-add-title-to-marker-or-shape?rq=1
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131447/adding-comments-using-leaflet-draw?rq=1